# Magento 2 Fresh Install Showing 'Whoops, our bad...' 404 page not found

Tags: magento2, 404-page, .htaccess, magento2.4.4

After install very fresh Magento 2, I am seeing **Whoops, our bad...** (404 Not Found) in all pages. Screenshot:
[image]

I am using Linux Mint OS.

Here is my steps:

1. Installed Apache version is `apache2 -v`:

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2020-08-12T19:46:17
```

2. Checked PHP Version: `PHP 7.4.18 (cli) (built: May  3 2021 11:27:06) ( NTS )`
3. Did execute: `sudo apt-get install curl wget gnupg`
4. Checked MySQL Version: `mysql  Ver 8.0.25-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))`
5. Checked composer version: `Composer version 2.0.7 2020-11-13 17:31:06`
6. Did execute the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.4-intl
sudo apt-get install php7.4-soap
sudo apt install php7.4-bcmath
sudo apt install php7.4-xsl

sudo apt install php7.4-ctype
sudo apt install php7.4-dom
sudo apt install php7.4-gd
sudo apt install php7.4-iconv
sudo apt install php7.4-mbstring
sudo apt install php7.4-simplexml
sudo apt install php7.4-zip
sudo apt install php7.4-libxml

sudo service apache2 restart
```

7. Installed and Start elasticsearch
8. Download Magento 2 using composer, Did execute the following commands:

```
cd www/
composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition magento-practice
cd magento-practice/
sudo chmod -R 777 ./
```

Created Database and installed the Magento 2:

```
php bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://localhost/magento-practice --db-host=localhost --db-name=magento_practice \
--db-user=dbadmin --db-password=Qwerty \
--admin-firstname=admin --admin-lastname=admin --admin-email=shahalom@mcqacademy.com --admin-user=admin --admin-password=786Admin \
--language=en_US --currency=USD --timezone=America/Chicago --use-rewrites=1 \
--backend-frontname=adminn
```

Then also esecute the following commands:

```
sudo php -dmemory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:upgrade
sudo php -dmemory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
sudo php -dmemory_limit=-1 bin/magento indexer:reindex
sudo php -dmemory_limit=-1 bin/magento cache:clean
sudo php -dmemory_limit=-1 bin/magento cache:flush

sudo chmod -R 777 ./
```

**Now edited the `.htaccess` From:**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pub/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/setup/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/update/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dev/
RewriteRule .* /pub/$0 [L]
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Into:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/magento-practice/pub/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/magento-practice/setup/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/magento-practice/update/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/magento-practice/dev/
RewriteRule .* /magento-practice/pub/$0 [L]
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

What I am doing wrong?

**Edit:**
Sofar I understand, the `.htaccess` is not creating from the `.htaccess.sample` while configuring/setup the magento2.

Comment: Hi!

Please provide more information: store URL (using example.com), full apache .htaccess and few samples of URLs that returns 404.

Comment: Looks like you misconfigured your apache it should point to `.../magento-root` directory, and you should not edit `.htaccess` file. Could you add your apache's vhost config to the question?

Comment: I have created a folder `magento-practice` as the root of the magento2 base which made URL `http://localhost/magento-practice`.

Comment: Have you tried installing with MySQL 5.7?

Comment: It has long been recommended to make the /pub subfolder the docroot. I believe that 2.4.2 makes this mandatory. You might also check your webserver logs and/or use browser tools to see if there are any unexpected redirects happening.

Comment: indeed you have fallen in the magento-in-subfolder problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should enable mod rewrite

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite;
sudo service apache2 restart;
```

For the virtualhost(please change the xxxx for specific site and match with your current setting up).
You should let it be separated with localhost.

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/local.xxx.com.conf;
```

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName local.xxxx.com

    DocumentRoot "/home/xxxx/Projects/xxxx"
    <Directory "/home/xxxx/Projects/xxxx">
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
    Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog "/home/xxxx/Projects/logs/error.log"
    CustomLog "/home/xxxx/Projects/logs/access.log" combined
</VirtualHost>
```

```
sudo a2ensite local.xxxx.com.conf;
sudo service apache2 restart;
```

Grand apache user to use the folders

```
sudo usermod -aG www-data $USER;
sudo chgrp www-data /home/xxxx/Projects;
sudo chmod -R g+rwx /home/xxxx/Projects;
```

Set permission for magento root folder if necessary

```
sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
sudo find ./media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
sudo find ./media -exec chmod 777 {} \;
sudo find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
sudo chmod 777 ./app/etc;
sudo chmod 644 ./app/etc/*.xml;
```

Keep original .htaccess you don't have to make changes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. mod rewrite modules was enabled. still no luck. :(

Answer (score 0):

> **Try This**

Create configuration file for host

> sudo cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/sa.com.conf

Now, modify the configuration files to match with our virtual hosts and put the below code.

> sudo gedit /etc/apache2/sites-available/sa.com.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin magento2@test.com
    ServerName sa.com.tn
    ServerAlias www.sa.com.tn
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/SA
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    <Directory /var/www/html/SA>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Enable virtual host configuration files

> sudo a2ensite sa.com.conf

Restart apache web server.

> sudo service apache2 restart

Add your virtual host like below and put code.

> gedit /etc/hosts

After adding the below line to this file and save the file.

> 127.0.0.1 sa.com.tn

> Now edit **core_config_data** table and put value **web/unsecure/base_url** & **web/secure/base_url** here like below

> http://sa.com.tn/

**Update**

> **Now edited the .htaccess :**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pub/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/setup/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/update/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dev/
RewriteRule .* pub/$0 [L]
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

***I Hope This Helps You.***

Comment: Thank You, still no luck.

Comment: @ShahAlom please change your .htaccess file like above. I update the answer.

Comment: @ShahAlom Have you try? Please check and update me.

Comment: I tried and still seeing the page not found error.

Answer (score 0):

**Option.1**

go to below configuration in admin

**Stores -> Configurations -> General ->Web  -> Search Engine Optimization -> Use Web Server Rewrites**

and **disable**  "Use Web Server Rewrites".

---

**Option.2**

run below command from ssh

```
php bin/magento config:set web/seo/use_rewrites 0 
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

---

if it works for you that mean issue with php rewrite module

hope this helps you :)

Comment: Every page is showing 404 error, how can i login into admin?

Comment: updated answer with option 2. please try this

Answer (score 0):

As you have apache2 server. Can you please check your **.htaccess** file exist? As this file is messed up in your setup.Can you replace  **.htaccess** file from default one ?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pub/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/setup/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/update/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dev/
RewriteRule .* /pub/$0 [L]
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

sometimes it's because of file permission and make sure rewrite is enabled

```
a2enmod rewrite
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're on 2.4.2 it's the magento-in-subfolder issue with the new .htaccess settings

> The [magento_root]/index.php file has been removed, and Magento now runs from /pub by default for Apache configurations. Stores that are served from subfolders will not work as expected and may display 404 errors

The installation instructions `bin/magento setup:install` still give an example with a subfolder I flagged it on github months ago :(

## simplest, if you are just starting:

- reinstall but not in a subfolder
- make the pub/ folder the server root
- things also work if you make the magento install main folder the document root, there's a config option

## If you can change the document root (essentially losing your subfolder)

- if you control your server config, don't need multiple apps in one instance, and don't want a "URL key" for the shop, just change the apache configuration to make the 'document root' be the pub folder in your magento install
- things also work if you make the magento install main folder the document root, old style way, there's a config option
- if you still want to have a url path showing for the shop, the workaround is simlinks inside the pub folder as per https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/release-notes/open-source-2-4-2.html#known-issues

## If you can't make pub or magento the document root:

simplest remains reinstall Magento (or move it) to your doc root.

Otherwise You will need to tweak your root .htaccess rewrites to pass things to the pub/ folder not the main folder

I banged my head on walls with that one but found that on my system it works IF I MADE THE FOLDER name different from the URL structure path. i.e. if you want "myshop" in the URL then create a folder called, say, "myshop-folder". (or have  no URL but a subfolder)

These are answers I gave in post https://magento.stackexchange.com/posts/332405 in March but should still work

**subfolder install that is invisible in url**

For testing purposes I have a test site upgraded to 2.4.2 and managed to find a config that uses a subfolder BUT the subfolder is invisible in the url.

- magento installed in magento2-path subfolder
- site working on [www.mywebsite.com](http://www.mywebsite.com)
- if magento2-path was visible in url, and therefore set up in the site url-path config or in stylesheets, that must be cleaned out
- [www.mywebsite.com/magento2-path](http://www.mywebsite.com/magento2-path) will 404

Note 2: to save work this does not have a local copy of the images and uses "static domain" for images so not certain it 100% correct for static files and probably some extra rule needed for pub/static

```
site-root
.htaccess
     magento2-path
     .htaccess
          pub
          .htaccess
```

the htaccess at the top has

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pub/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/setup/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/update/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dev/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/magento2-path/setup/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/magento2-path/update/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/magento2-path/dev/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/magento2-path/pub/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/magento2-path/
RewriteRule .* /magento2-path/pub/$0 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/pub/
RewriteRule .* /magento2-path/$0 [L]

DirectoryIndex index.php
```

the htaccess in magento2-path is modified to (the / in front of pub is removed)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^pub/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/setup/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/update/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dev/
RewriteRule .* pub/$0 [L]
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

the htaccess in `pub` is not modified, except to add any special old "migration" rules I had from migration from past modules or pages that are now gone

**attempt #2 subfolder (with redirect)**

UPDATE: I have found that for a site that used the magento install path in the URL I can make it redirect so the page shows (without that path) only **when the folder is renamed to not match the path** anymore. Otherwise requests get passed down the stack. You want to make sure your "root level" rewrites are used, not the magento one.

- magento was installed in magento2-path subfolder RENAME THIS FOLDER eg tomagento2-folder
- site working on [www.mywebsite.com](http://www.mywebsite.com)
- if magento2-path was visible in url, and therefore set up in the site url-path config or in stylesheets, that must be cleaned out
- [www.mywebsite.com/magento2-path/whatever](http://www.mywebsite.com/magento2-path/whatever)  redirects to [www.mywebsite.com/whatever](http://www.mywebsite.com/whatever) which displays correctly

  site-root
  .htaccess
  magento2-folder2
  .htaccess
  pub
  .htaccess

the htaccess at the top has (note: this is total overkill i'm sure only half the redirects are needed but not got time to clean)

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^/magento2-path/$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/magento2-path$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^magento2-path/$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^magento2-path$ / [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /magento2-path/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/magento2-path/setup/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/magento2-path/update/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/magento2-path/dev/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/magento2-path/pub/
RewriteRule ^magento2-path(.*) $1  [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /magento2-path/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/magento2-path/setup/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/magento2-path/update/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/magento2-path/dev/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/magento2-path/pub/
RewriteRule ^/magento2-path/(.*) /$1  [R=301,L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pub/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/setup/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/update/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dev/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/magento2-path/setup/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/magento2-path/update/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/magento2-path/dev/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/magento2-path/
RewriteRule .* /magento2-folder/pub/$0 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/pub/
RewriteRule .* /magento2-path/$0 [L]

DirectoryIndex index.php
```

the htaccess in magento2-folder and magento2-folder/pub is the same as above

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been mentioned here https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/32285.
My quick workaround is, update **.htaccess** in the magento base folder file following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^pub/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/setup/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/update/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dev/
RewriteRule .* pub/$0 [L]
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

(Aim to remove the slash before *pub*)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Actually I tried this and no luck :(