# Whoops, our bad

Tags: magento2, installation

it's been several times that I tried to make magento work but I always have the error page Whoops, our bad and I have tried everything so I am leaving it to you.

If you need capture or anything you can ask me thank you in advance

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: yes sure i edit my question

Comment: Take a look at https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/337808/magento-2-fresh-install-showing-whoops-our-bad-404-page-not-found

Comment: I've seen this before and nothing happened

Comment: Can you take Magento out of the subfolder and see if you still have this issue?

Comment: Ok i try this option

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm going to try this tomorrow because I just finished my day and I'll let you know anyway thank you

Comment: Hello, 
I'm sorry to answer only now but it's always the same things even changing the directory